# static website with Jekyll: bundler: failed to load command: jekyll

Tags: ruby, rubygems, static, jekyll

running bundle exec jekyll serve       ....
I get this (the project is a clone of one I already made...jekyll static website)

do I need some new or old version of jekyll, ruby, or some gem issue?
tried a ton of different things I found online.  still stuck in the mud.  Thanks for any help!

```
bundler: failed to load command: jekyll 
(/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/mystie/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/bin/jekyll)
<internal:....y/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': 
....../vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/commands/new.rb:168: 
syntax error, unexpected `end', expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
```

Comment: I guess I just need to completely remove and initialize jekyll/gems/ruby/etc...?   I didn't have this issue before with a previous static jekyll website.  I'm using Millenial as a base flow. again have error. Error: could not read file ....../ruby/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb: Invalid date '<%= Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z') %>': Document 'ruby/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb' does not have a valid date in the YAML front matter. ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT

Comment: Perhaps this? https://hjerpbakk.com/blog/2020/05/25/your-site-could-not-be-built

Comment: just fwiw... it's working now.   deleted repository and just started with a fresh clone and integrated website guts of the jekyll template.  no idea still what the issue was.